# Blowing into the mic to play 1 sound instead of multiple timer triggers

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, avaudioplayer

I am using this great tutorial [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) to detect when someone blows into the mic.

My end goal is playing one single sound when someone is blowing into the phone and stopping it when they are not blowing into it; however, since this example is timer-based, it is triggering this `if` statement 30 times every second (see the example code in the tutorial for the timer).

```
if (lowPassResults > 0.95) {
    NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");

    self.audioSource = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:audioSound volume:1.0 pitch:1.0 pan:0 loop:NO];

}   

if (lowPassResults  < 0){
    NSLog(@"PLEASE STOP?");
    [self.keyCSource stop];

}
```

Anybody have any ideas to listen for the "blow" and and if it's being blown into then play the ObjectAL sound **ONCE** and then stop it when it's not being blown into?

Comment: Don't know about your specific issue, but perhaps you could look into and adapt key debouncing algos?

Answer (score 0):

*As far as I understand you can detect the blow and your problem is, that you only want to play the sound once. Otherwise ignore my answer...*

Create a property `@property BOOL blowDetected`, set it to `YES` when the blow is detected and  to `NO` when you stop the sound (or when you are ready to detect another blow). Then only play the sound `if (!self.blowDetected)`

A bit more detail:

```
if (meterResults > 0.95) {
    NSLog(@"isPlaying");
    _isPlaying = YES;
}
```

So far so good, but here you also want to start playing your sound and only if `_isPlaying == NO`

```
if (!_isPlaying && meterResults > 0.95) {
    self.keyCSource = [[ ... and so on
    _isPlaying = YES;
}
```

Then, when `meterResult` drops down

```
if (lowPassResults  < 0){
    _isPlaying = NO;
    [self.keyCSource stop];
}
```

Comment: That is exactly correct - let me try this concept. I will let you know how it works out! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian! The second if statement though isn't firing. Any idea why?  I am working with it on here if you'd like to look at the code? https://www.stypi.com/seanherman/Bool-ing

Comment: How can a BOOL like _isPlaying be greater than a number? Don't get that part I suppose.

Comment: If you don't understand what `if (!_isPlaying && meterResults > 0.95) {` is doing, I suggest you take a basic programming course.

Comment: I understand what that is doing - completely. What I do not get is why it isn't firing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for you because you restart the sound 30 times per second for as long as your low pass result exceeds the threshold. Here is how you could fix this.

Make sure that you have some kind of persistent flag `BOOL is_playing` and set that to `NO` initially. When the threshold is exceeded, test for `is_playing`. Only if that is `NO` invoke `playEffect` with `loop:YES`, and set `is_playing` to `YES`.

If the low pass result is below your threshold `stopAllEffects` and set `is_playing` to `NO`. You should also reconsider whether your lower threshold should really be zero. It could be quite a bit higher, up to 0.95.

Comment: I think you're completely right. But I have a quick question on getting it working... could you look at my code here and see if I am doing it right?  http://www.stypi.com/seanherman/Bool-ing

Comment: I've set the bool and I set it to NO initially but playing the sound once only when it's NO, is confusing me a bit?